# custom Page content fields not working in SharePoint 2010 custom layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a custom content type for custom layouts in SharePoint 2010. I have a number of Page content fields defined (PageContent1A, PageContent1B, PageContent1C, PageContent2A, etc...) however, when selecting it "click here to add new content" in the edit mode of the page using the custom layout, it (1) won't open, (2) When I do get one to work PageContent2c, and check the html, it shows the code from another page content PageContent2B. See the attached screenshot. I have been troubleshooting this for days and cannot seem to find why this is not working. I am using the following doc type in the custom masterpage: HELP!!!!!
[image]

```
    <%@ Page language="C#"   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>
```

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

```
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
```

```
   <div>
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PageContent2B" runat="server" AllowTables="true"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>    
    <hr class="style-one"/>
   </div>

     <div>      
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="Zone3" runat="server" title="Zone 3"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
 </div>


<div>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="Zone4" runat="server" title="Zone 4"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>     
    </div>
 </div><!--end col center-->
```

```
  <div>
  <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="Page Content" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
  </div>

 <div>
 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="Zone1" runat="server" title="Zone 1" AllowPersonalization="false" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"      Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>      
 </div>

<div>    
 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="Zone2" runat="server" title="Zone 2" AllowPersonalization="false" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"          Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to have the IE designation set to IE=8, not IE= edge in the master page. Then everything was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a mistake in the markup.  Could you post the ASPX code for the page?

Are you using Visual Studio or trying to do this in Designer?

Comment: doing this in Designer

Comment: will post the code as soon as I find out how to

Comment: how do I upload a file?

Comment: I am using a transitional xhtml doctype  however I noticed in the masterpage that there are some  SP controls that SPD indicates not permitted such as:

Comment: <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico"/>
<SharePoint:SPPageManager runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SPHelpPageComponent Visible="false" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/controls.css %>" runat="server"/>

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code ... so here is what I would do to get a solution as fast as possible if I were in your position:    I would copy my current code to a safe place (textpad) for reference and then I would replace it with the code from an existing layout page with the same number of webpart zones. Then I would make sure I can successfully use the unchanged copy of the existing layout I just made.  Finally, I would start making small changes to the position of the webpart zones using designer, checking that I didn't break anything as I go, until it looks the way I want it to.

Comment: I based the content type on the welcome page, should I have used a different one?

Comment: So you know which control in the nightandday master is associated with page content? Maybe I accidentally turned off a control needed for this to work. Same thing happened when I opened the Article layout page and looked at the Richtext field config, used it in my page and it did not work

Comment: I figured it out, it was the UX compatible line , set to IE-Edge and it had to be IE=8